# Updating Trigger Table Values Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am not able to update a table after the following trigger added. Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM(
item_id  DECIMAL(10) NOT NULL,
description  VARCHAR(30),
price  DECIMAL(10),
PRIMARY KEY (item_id));

CREATE TABLE Item_price_history (
history_id  DECIMAL(10) NOT NULL,
item_id  DECIMAL(10) NOT NULL,
line_price DECIMAL(10,2),
new_line_price DECIMAL(10,2),
modified DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (HISTORY_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (ITEM_ID) REFERENCES item);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Item_price_history
AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT ON ITEM 
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO item_price_history(item_id, line_price, 
    new_line_price,modified) 
   select item_id,:OLD.price,:New.price, SYSTIMESTAMP from item;
END;
```

Now if I use the following Update commands, I get this error:

```
UPDATE item_price_history
SET line_price = 4
WHERE ITEM_ID=ITEM.ITEM_ID and ITEM.DESCRIPTION='Spoon';
```

***Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "ITEM"."DESCRIPTION": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:

*Action:***

Any help or suggestions or advice?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this:

```
UPDATE item_price_history 
SET line_price = 4
WHERE item_id IN (SELECT item_id
                  FROM ITEM
                  WHERE description = 'Spoon');
```

Comment: Gave an error, SQL Command not properly ended. I don't think from ITEM i is allowed in update clause

Comment: Updated my answer. Could u please try again? @user2501165

Comment: It should update, I am surprised. Schema looks good to me. Could you please edit your question and put some example data, maybe? We are updating line_price by the way, not new_line_price, you aware of it right?

Comment: Run the subquery itself only and make sure it is returning some IDs and they are existing in the item_price_history table under the item_id column to test

Comment: This makes sense, I didn't have any data in item_price_history table. I am assuming some data needs to be there, right?

Comment: Yes. The data for item_price_history table has to be inserted. We cannot "update" any data which is not existing yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below Merge as well. This will not update anything as there are no records in item table with Spoon Description and item_id.
Not sure what you wanted to achieve. I see you created a trigger. The trigger fires only when there is an insert/update on item not on item_price_history.

```
merge INTO item_price_history tgt USING
(SELECT item_id, description FROM item
) src ON (tgt.item_id = src.item_id AND src.description = 'Spoon')
WHEN matched THEN
  UPDATE SET line_price = 4;
```

--Updates zero records

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

`update ITEM_PRICE_HISTORY SET line_price = 4
WHERE item_id IN (SELECT i.item_id FROM ITEM WHERE i.description = 'Spoon');`